# $y'' = qy$ with $q$ positive function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the following differential equation :
$y'' = qy$ where $q : \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+^*$ is a continuous, positive function.

I take $y$ the solution of the equation satisfying :

- $y(0) = 1$
- $y'(0) = a \in \mathbb{R}$

I have to show that there exists a constant $k$ such as $y$ has a zero iff $a < k$

I already showed that $y\times y'$ has at most one zero by using Rolle's theorem
I also think that $a < 0$ because otherwise, $y$ would be an increasing function and would never vanish.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take $a$ negative very large and apply the Taylor expansion with quadratic remainder term for times $\sim 1/|a|$. This should easily give a root.

Comment: It does not give the value of k...

Comment: You only need to show that such a $k$ exists, for that apply the intermediate-value theorem in some not completely trivial fashion.

Answer (score 0):

$y''=py$

$y''y'=pyy'$

$y'^2=py^2-\int p'y^2 dx$ by integration by parts.

For a vanishingly small region about a zero of y, that integral is zero. This implies a zero of y happens for a zero of the first derivative.

The second derivative is always non-negative, so the first derivative is monotonically increasing. Once positive, the first derivative will remain positive, so it only has a zero if it has a negative initial value.

The first derivative will exceed any initial value, so any $a<0$ will work. So $k=0$.

Comment: If I take $y = 1/(1+x)$, $y'' = 2/(1+x)^3$ and $y''= 2/(1+x)^2 y$. $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=-1$